# Como pegar valores de array javascript/jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax e retornando os dados pelo php com json_encode

lado do servidor:

```
 $id=1;
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){
   $id = $_POST['id']; 
 }else{
   http_response_code(400);
 }
 $produto = listaAssociada($id);
 echo json_encode(listaAssociada($id));
```

função listaAssociada

```
  $query = "SELECT p.nome,p.descricao as produtodescricao,p.img as produtoimg,e.titulo,e.descricao as explicacaodescricao,e.infoadicional,e.img as explicacaoimg FROM Produto as p inner join Explicacao as e on p.idExplicacao=e.idExplicacao where p.idProduto= $id"; 
$consulta = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) != 0) {
        while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $resultados['nome'] = $item['nome'];
            $resultados['produtodescricao'] = $item['produtodescricao'];
            $resultados['explicacaodescricao'] = $item['explicacaodescricao'];
            $resultados['titulo'] = $item['titulo'];

        }

        return $resultados;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
```

parte do script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var produtos;
  var i=0;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/produto.php",
    data:{
      id:1
    },
    error:function(e){

    },

    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
  });
 });
```

já tentei json.parse não funciona, tentei foreach também nada.
quero poder pegar os valores separados para fazer por exemplo

```
   var x = data.nome;
```

quando dou alert do data retorna.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta colocando `dataType:"json",` no Ajax

Comment: quando coloquei o dataType:"json", parou de funcionar, ate um simples alert('oi'); esta dando essas duas mensagens no console:  GET http://localhost/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
produto.php:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada. Deveria retornar um JSON assim: `{nome: "nome do item", produtodescricao: "descricao do produto", explicacaodescricao: "explicacao do produto", titulo: "titulo"}explicacaodescricao: "explicacao do produto"nome: "nome do item"produtodescricao: "descricao do produto"titulo: "titulo"}`

Comment: psé não sei se talvez não seja o jeito que estou armazenando no vetor do lado do php. mas no proprio script eu consigo acessar como array direto, faço $produto = listaAssociada($id);
 echo $produto['nome'] . "<br>". e printa direitinho.

Comment: Qual é a versão do jQuery estas a usar?

Comment: a ultima  versao 3.4.1 .

Answer (score 0):

No lado do servidor, inicie com:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Isso antes do `$id=1;`, e no script, ao invés de usar o alert, tente utilizar o `console.log(data);`.

Comment: dando um console.log ele aparece a mesma coisa que no alert, e eu nao consigo acessar com data['nome'] por exemplo é dito como indefinido.

Comment: ai tenta data.nome, data.produtodescricao, data.explicacaodescricao, ...
Agora ele é um json, então é só colocar ponto "." e o nome do que você vai querer.

Comment: também não funciona.

Comment: E se colocar apenas data, o que aparece Gabriella?

Comment: aquilo que mostrei na imagem

Comment: mas no console.log também?

Comment: sim mesma coisa =(

Comment: Olha, eu não sei se ajuda muito, mas deixei em apenas dois arquivos, o produto.php e o index.html, segue eles:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/138DhHiswTrbyoyMiSm_x1M3QWHlhGbxr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: psé não funcionou muito, mas obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O retorno mostrado no alert indica que é um array e não um objeto. Desta forma, você deve acessar utilizando o nome do índice:

```
 var x = data['nome'];
```

Comment: isso da undefined .

Comment: se você executar `alert (data.keys())` o que é mostrado?